# What just happened in the market?

Tags: market, news

How can a day trader figure out what event might have triggered a sudden spike in volume that occurs after hours?

Example: a quarter past midnight (NYSE time), the ES Dec 2016 future is crawling slowly... then suddenly, THIS:

[image: Volume spike]

From a volume of zero, to a volume of 1000 in 5 seconds.

I know that ES futures volume picks up after midnight, but this occured 15 minutes later, and the general question is,

*Where can one find rapid-fire market news after hours?*

Some Twitter account perhaps? Traders' chatrooms?

Answer (score 5):

What happened was the BoJ announcement. Such large scale news are well covered in mainstream media (ft, bloomberg, etc) and also mainstream anti-media (eg zerohedge).

Comment: also note that according to https://www.boj.or.jp/en/announcements/calendar/index.htm/ (if I'm reading it correctly) the announcement was announced well in advance (the 16th at least) as most announcements of this kind are. Most announcements are also covered live by a large number of media outlets.